# Custom form field in Symfony2, unwanted attribute inherited

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm getting some troubles understanding how Symfony2 **custom form field types** work. I need to create a new type with some custom attributes (HTML5 `data-*`) based on data passed to `MyType`.

**The problem is** that after adding `MyType` to the main form, its label inherits the `data-*` attribute.

```
// Add MyType to the main form

$builder->add('somename', new MyType(), array('label' => 'my label'));
```

This is my custom type:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
       $source = isset($option['source']) ? json_encode($option['source']) : '';

        return array(
            'attr' => array(
                'data-source' => $source
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName() { return 'mytype'; }

    public function getParent(array $options) { return 'text'; }

}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying that your label html entity ends up with a data-source attribute when it renders?  If so then I can help with that.  If it is something else then maybe not.

Comment: @Cerad yes, label has exactly the same attributes as the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: as far as i can understand passing `array('attr' => array('myattr1' => 'value1'))` as option for the builder is intended as common attributes for the builder and all **its child elements**. This is why, for example, passing `array('required' => false)` at **form level** will disable HTML5 built-in client side validation for each field inside that form.

(Always looking for a better solution) i'll post my way, inspired by this [blog post](http://henrik.bjrnskov.dk/symfony2-recaptcha-v2/): a **custom form field** with **view attributes** and a **Twig block** to create new attributes.

```
class TypeheadType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->setAttribute('mode',  $options['mode'])
            ->setAttribute('items', $options['items']);

    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
    {

        $view
            ->set('mode',  $form->getAttribute('mode'))
            ->set('items', $form->getAttribute('items'));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {

        return array(
            'mode'  => 'single',
            'items' => 10
        );
    }

    public function getName() { return 'typehead'; }

    public function getParent(array $options) { return 'field'; }

}
```

The new form type should be register as a service and alias should match what's being returned by `getName()` (is this mandatory? dunno...):

```
form.type.typehead:
  class: Acme\HelloBundle\Form\Type\TypeheadType
  tags:
    - { name: form.type, alias: typehead }
```

New field creation (elsewhere):

```
$builder->add('myfield', 'typehead', array('items' => 15));
```

In Twig form theme widget block (pattern for name is `as getName() . '_widget`) you can use view attributes setted in `TypeheadType`:

```
{% block typehead_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <input type="text" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} 
        {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}
        data-items="{{ items }}" data-mode="{{ mode }}" />
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock typehead_widget %}
```

And, finally:

```
{{ form_row(form.myfield) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the basic problem is that label picks up all the attributes on the widget.  I don't really understand why they designed it this way but if you look at:

```
{# Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig #}
{% block generic_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' required'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor%}>{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

You can see that generic_label (called by default) dumps out each attribute.

I overrode the default with:

```
{% block generic_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' required'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    <label {{ block('label_attributes') }}>{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{% block label_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %}{% if (attrname == 'for' or attrname == 'class') %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endif %}{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

My label_attributes block only puts out for and class attributes which is all I have needed so far.  Again, the default implementation is confusing and I'm probably missing something obvious but the override seems to work okay.  Use the form_theme to bring in the new forms file:

```
{% form_theme form 'ZaysoCoreBundle:Layout:fields.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Upvote for the twig solution, thanks. But i've found a better oneand i'll post it asap.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing the alternate solution.  My solution works but, as I indicated, I always had the feeling I was missing something obvious.

Comment: Answer posted, let me know what do you think about it. Thanks.